# Mac Big Sur Python terminal REPL does not refresh when pressing arrow keys or backspace

Tags: python, macos, terminal, anaconda, read-eval-print-loop

When I started to use my new Mac (system: Big Sur), I found that in the python REPL in the terminal, arrow keys and backspace performed weirdly. It is not the common issue found on the Internet that pressing them will generate escape characters (something like [[^A) and I have already installed `readline` and `gnureadline`. This problem still existed whether I used Bash or ZSH shell.

After some exploration, I figured out that the problem is that the REPL does not refresh after I pressing those keys, but it did correctly receive the instructions of arrow keys or backspace key; that is, if I totally ignore the middle result displayed on the terminal, it would just work find. I don't know how to fix this. Below I will use backspace and left arrow key to illustrate the problem ( | means the position of the cursor):

Start the REPL:

```
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 07:03:16) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> |
```

Type "abc":

```
>>> abc|
```

Press backspace (notice that the cursor is **forwarded** one character):

```
>>> abc |
```

Press enter:

```
>>> abc 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ab' is not defined
>>> |
```

From the error message, it seems that I indeed deleted the last character c as expected, it is just that the REPL screen did not refresh and did not display the correct thing.

As another example, left arrow key:
Type abc:

```
>>> abc|
```

Press left arrow key (nothing changed):

```
>>> abc|
```

Type d:

```
>>> abcdc|
```

Type e:

```
>>> abcdcec|
```

Type enter:

```
>>> abcdcec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'abdec' is not defined
>>> |
```

Again, the terminal correctly received the instruction of left arrow key (i.e., the `de` is inserted to the left of `c`), but it did not display it correctly.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you type in terminal `stty sane; python` to see if it can be fixed ?

Comment: @Philippe No, the problem still persisted

Comment: Are you using the standard Terminal.app or some other terminal emulator? What is the value of the TERM environment variable?

Comment: @TurePålsson I am using the standard Terminal.app. I am using ZSH shell. The value of TERM is xterm-256color